# Cannot declared a function named "in"?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here's a script that throws a syntax error if and only if the function is named `in`:

```bsh
in() {
        echo 0;
}
```

> line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `in'

Why is that so? I cannot give this function a different name, so what should I do?

Comment: @zevzek The actual script is split into several sub command, and "in" is one of them. I'm using rici's solution from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638248/sub-commands-with-bash. With his solution, the backslash is not requires. Thanks, I just needed to declare it, but I'm still wondering why `in() { }` wouldn't work.

Comment: This might help: `type in`

Comment: Try to get a basic understanding of *syntax*, *identifiers* and *keywords*. In most languages you cannot use keywords for identifiers. Guess what could happen if you'd name your function `if` or `return`.

Comment: @U.Windl I mean no disrespect, but please take a look at the question's redaction date and the other replies.

Comment: @B.Bergeron What is your concrete criticism? That I repeat what someone else had said before, or that I responded late? Anyone can find a question or answer years after it had been written. If posters just seek for a quick response to their actual needs, SO/SE is probably the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is a `bash` keyword and is reserved. You can't use it. Read `man bash`.

Comment: Open `man bash` and type `/in`. `man bash` is a bad resource for quick references. Can you instead explain what's this `in` keyword and how to deal with it?

Comment: `in` is often used with `for`.  e.g. `for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo "$i"; done`.   Type `help for` in bash.

Comment: Refer to "RESERVED WORDS" in man bash.